# How to check uploaded xml is valid using java

Tags: java, xml-parsing

I am working on XML parsing in JAVA. While uploading the file i can able to validate whether it is an valid XML file or not. But if i am saving some other text file with extension(XML) how i can able to check uploaded xml is valid XML or not.

Please anyone help on this...Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
XElement element;

TRY {
      element=XElement.Load(filename);
      -- Add code to upload file here
      --Because if you reach here then it meant your file successfully 
   }  CATCH (exception ex) {
      -- If the code fail put code to handle the fail here.
   }
```

Comment: If i am using your above code it ask to create a class XElement. Please suggest us

Answer (score 0):

Validness of an XML file has two aspects:

1. Well-formed XML file: XML file conforms to the general rules of XML (XML shall have a root element, attributes shall be defined double quot etc.)
2. Valid XML file: XML file conforms to a specific schema (DTD or XSD)

By the term "valid", I think you mean "well-formed" XML file. The only way to completely determine whether a XML file is well-formed or not is to fully parse it.

XML file is a simple text file. Not a good way but you can check '<' character as the first character. Whether XML declaration or root element, after empty spaces, every XML  file starts with '<' character.
Assuming that you know the encoding of the file, you can determine whether your text file is not an XML file (but not the other way) by this way.

Comment: Is there any sample code in java to check the above scenario if yes please share